# È corretto dire “un terzo d'ora”?

Tags: word-usage

In italiano si usano le espressioni **mezz'ora** e **un quarto d'ora**.

È corretto dire **un terzo d'ora**?

Comment: Nemmeno sotto tortura (beh, diciamo leggera). Dalle mie parti esiste soltanto "venti minuti". Ma ammetto che "un terzo" è davvero molto divertente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'espressione, per quanto insolita, sembra essere stata usata in passato più di quel che si possa immaginare. Dagli esempi che si possono trovare sembra si tratti comunque di un uso poco comune, forse arcaico.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20terzo%20d%27ora&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20terzo%20d%27%20ora%3B%2Cc0) “un terzo d'ora”:

> - Aggiunsi di nuovo ugual quantità di acqua, e pur i lombrichi vi morirono ***in poco più di un terzo d' ora***. E di nuovo aggiuntavi nuova a quaidugiarono altri lombrichi a morirvi più di quattr' ore. Hanno molta ragione i Medici, per esterninare i verni ...([*Vocabolario degli accademici della Crusca*, 1804](https://books.google.it/books?id=olpCAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA120&dq=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=RdxHVaCiEozTUbiigcgL&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22un%20terzo%20d'ora%22&f=false))
> - ... facilità a venir fuora per le vie della orina conforme talvolta ha fatto. Continui dunque il siero. Lo pigli al solito peso delle sei once. Lo pigli la mattina intorno alle dodici ore non importando ***un terzo d'ora prima, ovvero un terzo d'ora dopo.*** ([*Consulti Medici*, Francesco Redi](https://books.google.it/books?id=M9JQAQAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&dq=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=u9lHVYSGMofeUc_LgYgK&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ))
> - Perciò tornai indietro in direzione della carovana, mettendo in pratica il sistema che avevo appreso dalla guida, e mi misi a correre velocemente ***per circa un terzo d'ora***, cercando ogni tanto di afferrare qualche voce e qualche luce della ...([*Gli annali dell'Africa Italiana*, Ministero dell'Africa Italiana](https://books.google.it/books?id=QBIUAAAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&dq=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=u9lHVYSGMofeUc_LgYgK&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw))
> - L'operazione durò, ricordo benissimo, ***meno di un terzo d'ora*** e si compì assai felicemente. La bella bionda dormiva, cloroformizzata, e in quel sonno di cloroformio, a tratti, sospirava o si lamentava sotto l'incubo morale e direi quasi fisico, con ...([*La vita a Napoli*, Salvatore Di Giacomo](https://books.google.it/books?id=tN8bAQAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&dq=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=u9lHVYSGMofeUc_LgYgK&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCQ))
> - PIPPA. Che ladra. 
>     NANNA. In questo io compariva in sala, ed egli: «Io vengo a far riverenzia a vostra Signoria»; e pigliandomi la mano, me la basciucchiava bavosamente. E postosi a giornear meco, ***stato così un terzo d'ora,*** ([*Sei giornate*, Pietro Aretino](https://books.google.it/books?id=80JRAQAAIAAJ&q=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&dq=%22un%20terzo%20d%27ora%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=5NpHVbesFMbSU6ergNAG&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBDgK))

Comment: This link to Ngram gives "No valid ngrams to plot!" to me.

Comment: @Charo idem, però parte già precompilato, e cliccando il bottone di ricerca funziona.

Comment: @Josh61: Si tratta forse di libri antichi? Puoi indicare i riferimenti bibliografici di queste citazioni?

Comment: Quest'argomento è davvero interessante e penso che si potrebbe approfondire. Sono curiosa di sapere in quale periodo storico e in quali contesti si usasse "un terzo d'ora".

Comment: Si tratta dunque di libri del Cinquecento, del Seicento e dell'Ottocento. Soltanto quello del Ministero dell'Africa Italiana è più recente (1940).

Comment: Sì, come dicevo sopra, penso si tratti di un'espressione arcaica, sostituita da *20 minuti.* In realtà, essendo un'ora composta da 60 minuti, un terzo è una porzione logica.

Comment: Ma è curioso constatare come oggigiorno tante persone abbiano difficoltà a capire cosa sia 1/3 (in Spagna è lo stesso). Forse nel passato, in Italia, era diverso? Sarebbe interessante di sapere se "un terzo d'ora" si usasse nel linguaggio popolare o soltanto in registri colti.

Comment: Probabilmente, vi sono difficoltà nell'uso delle espressioni matematicamente corrette ma raramente usate. Ad esempio, ho messo a disagio una commessa chiedendo dodici etti di pane. Avrei dovuto dire "un chilogrammo e due etti"?

Comment: Beh la lingua esiste per farsi capire! Potrei benissimo dire "mi dia -e^{i pi} etto di pane per favore" e sarebbe matematicamente esatto ma ovviamente ridicolo. La risposta alla domanda : "Si dice in italiano 1/3 di ora" è "No, non l'ho mai sentito dire da nessuno e suonerebbe molto strano.". Che poi possa essere stato usato da qualche parte, e molto tempo fa, è un altro discorso

Comment: @Ant - il fatto è che sembra sia stata usata in passato ma non come scherzo, il che rende la questione interessante a mio avviso.

Comment: Assolutamente! Però rispondendo pragmaticamente a uno che chiede se si usa in italiano direi decisamente di no :-) Poi la questione del quando sia stata usata è perchè è sicuramente interessante :)

Comment: Concordo in pieno e nessuno, penso, ha dubbi a riguardo. L'attenzione si è spostata sull'uso che questa espressione, apparentemente, aveva in passato.

Comment: Josh, mi sono permesso di esplicitare meglio nella risposta, a scanso di equivoci, che si tratta di usi di altri tempi.

Comment: @DaG - ho provato a fare la stessa domanda su ELU http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244458/i-waited-for-a-third-of-an-hour ma non ci sono state risposte con novita sostanziali. l'atteggiamento e' di un naturale scetticismo sull'uso di questa espressione. Eppure sia in italiano che in inglese risulta in molti libri di varia natura. (mistero non risolto)

Answer (score 11):

Si potrebbe dire e – se l'interlocutore ha familiarità con l'aritmetica – si capirebbe che cosa si intende, ma suonerebbe scherzoso.

(Ho un amico che ogni tanto dice cose come «Sono le 11 meno un quinto», cioè le 10.48, ma appunto per scherzo.)

Comment: Bello "meno un quinto".

Comment: Anch'io lo dico :)

Comment: @Antonio: Cos'è quello che dici? Un terzo o un quinto d'ora?

Comment: @Charo Un quinto, ma è per scherzo.

Comment: La mia esperienza, confermata anche da altri, è che parecchia gente penserebbe che un terzo d'ora è meno di un quarto d'ora. Discutevo pochi giorni fa con una studentessa, che lavora part-time in una pizzeria: non è raro che qualcuno chieda un quarto di pizza e poi si corregga chiedendo un ottavo, che è di più. `:)`

Comment: @egreg. Come, un ottavo è più di un quarto?!? Se non ho completamente scordato le lezioni di matematica delle medie, un quarto corrisponde al 25 percento di una cosa, mentre un ottavo è poco più di un dodicesimo. Se stessimo parlando di un dollaro, un quarto di dollaro sono 25 centesimi, un ottavo di dollaro sarebbero circa 12 centesimi...

Comment: @Paola *Tu* lo sai! Purtroppo non tutti. `;-)`

Comment: @Paola, sei brava ad assecondare l'ironia di egreg, ma quando dici “un dodicesimo” intendi invece “12%”, vero?

Comment: Succede anche in USA http://mentalfloss.com/article/76144/why-no-one-wanted-aws-third-pound-burger

Answer (score 8):

**Dipende** da cosa intendi con "corretto".

@DaG giustamente sostiene che grammaticalmente è valida, e che l'interlocutore può capirla.

Ma è bene notare che non è un'espressione d'uso comune, con tutta probabilità se lo dici a qualcuno, questi non l'ha mai sentito dire prima d'ora, e su due piedi potrebbe non cogliere al volo cosa intendi. Chi non è bravo in matematica probabilmente non avrà idea di cosa intendi neanche se gli dai tempo per pensarci.

Insomma, **se il tuo scopo è essere capito**, di' "20 minuti", che è l'espressione corretta.

Comment: _(la tentazione di far la battuta e scrivere "di' 10 minuti" è stata forte)_

Answer (score 3):

Potrà essere formalmente corretto ma assolutamente non utilizzato e arcaico. Si usano **tre quarti d'ora** e **meno un quarto** oltre alle espressioni citate, ma mai sentito dire un terzo d'ora in vita mia.

Answer (score 2):

È tecnicamente corretto, ma non lo dice/scrive nessuno attualmente. Il concetto stesso di corretto è  aleatorio, grammaticalmente  l'espressione lo è , ma le lingue sono "composte" dalle persone che le parlano e dato che nessuno lo direbbe, tendenzialmente è "sbagliato".