# Frase interrogativa: "È corretto ...?", "... è corretto?" oppure "È ... corretto?"

Tags: sentences, word-order, interrogatives

Nei commenti a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5473/707) si è accennato un'argomento interessante: quello dell'ordinamento delle parole in una frase interrogativa. Ho pensato che questo argomento meriti una domanda perché, almeno per me, non è per niente chiaro.

Ho cercato informazioni sull'ordine delle parti della frase in una frase interrogativa nel libro *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo (edizioni ELI) e ho trovato questo:

> Per le frasi interrogative senza interrogativi l'ordine di base delle parti della frase è uguale a quello delle frasi affermative; come per queste, esso varia a seconda del valore che si vuole attribuire ai singoli elementi. Normalmente si tende a mettere in fondo alla frase la parte su cui si concentra la domanda.

In questo libro appaiono questi esempi:

> - Milena parte? (possibile completamento: Oppure resta qui?)
> - Parte Milena? (possibile completamento: Oppure parte Maria?)
> - Dai il libro a Piero? (possibile completamento: Oppure a Milena?)
> - Dai a Piero il libro? (possibile completamento: O gli dai il giornale?)

Consideriamo una frase interrogativa con la struttura che appare nel titolo della domanda, cioè

> - È corretto ...?
> - ... è corretto?
>
> oppure
>
> - È ... corretto?

Ammettiamo che si vogliano mettere in rilievo le parole che sostituiscono i punti di sospensione "..." ("l'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase", per esempio) appunto perché su queste parole si vuol concentrare la nostra domanda. Dopo aver riflettuto un po', mi pare che "È ... corretto?" sia un calco della struttura tipica della frase interrogativa in inglese ("Is that correct?") e che non abbia molto senso in italiano. Riguardo alle altri due alternative però, quali sarebbero corrette? Se ambedue sono corrette, quale forma mette più di rilievo che la nostra domanda è precisamente sulle parole che sostituiscono i punti di sospensione "..."?

Ad esempio,

> - È corretto l'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase?
>
> oppure
>
> - L'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase è corretto?

Un altro esempio tratto da [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5457/707):

> - È corretto dire "un terzo d'ora"?
>
> oppure
>
> - Dire "un terzo d'ora" è corretto?

Comment: «Ammettiamo che si vogliono mettere»… Il verbo «ammettere», nell’accezione di «supporre», richiede il congiuntivo, non l’indicativo, perciò: «Ammettiamo che si **vogliano** mettere…».

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Grazie mille! Ho fatto la correzione.

Comment: Di nulla. :-) Non potevo correggere direttamente la domanda perché la correzione era troppo breve.

Comment: Io uso “È corretto ...” perché rende subito il senso della domanda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma «È [qualcosa] corretto?» non è idiomatica, e suona piuttosto come un calco sintattico dall’inglese. Premesso che stiamo parlando di interrogative dirette totali, ossia di domande che riguardano l’intera frase e non solo un suo elemento, vediamo quel che ci dice l’*Enciclopedia dell’Italiano* («[Interrogative dirette](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-dirette_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/)», par. 3.1, grassetto mio) riguardo alla disposizione degli elementi:

> Nelle interrogative dirette totali la disposizione degli elementi che
>   costituiscono la frase è notevolmente libera, come dimostrano gli
>   esempi che seguono, nei quali i costituenti frasali sono sempre gli
>   stessi, ma la loro collocazione è di volta in volta diversa:
>
> (21) Carla, domani, potrà prendere l’aereo?
>
> (22) potrà prendere l’aereo domani, Carla?
>
> (23) l’aereo, domani, Carla potrà prenderlo?
>
> (24) l’aereo, Carla, potrà prenderlo domani?
>
> (25) domani, Carla potrà prendere l’aereo?
>
> (26) Carla potrà prendere l’aereo, domani?
>
> Naturalmente, **la diversa collocazione delle parole non è priva di
>   conseguenze sul significato della domanda e sull’orientamento della
>   risposta. A seconda di dove vengono collocati, i diversi costituenti
>   frasali vengono tematizzati o focalizzati**, cioè messi in evidenza (➔
>   focalizzazioni), diventando in questo modo l’argomento centrale della
>   domanda: così, per es., mentre in (21) e in (22) il centro della
>   domanda è Carla, in (23) e in (24) il centro della domanda è l’aereo;
>   infine, in (25) e in (26) il centro della domanda è domani.

Un elemento assumerà rilievo se verrà posto «ai margini» della frase, in quelle che, comunemente, si chiamano «dislocazioni a sinistra/destra» (ma che, razionalmente, sarebbe meglio chiamare «anticipazioni/posticipazioni», giacché la lingua parlata ha il primato su quella scritta e, parlando, non c’è una destra e una sinistra).

Venendo dunque alla domanda, e al nostro esempio, se vogliamo mettere in rilievo un particolare elemento, poniamo «l’uso del congiuntivo», che in questo caso funge da soggetto, dobbiamo metterlo in fondo alla frase, rompendo il normale ordine soggetto-predicato:

> È corretto, in questa frase, **l’uso del congiuntivo**?

Viceversa, se volessimo concentrarci sulla **correttezza** dell’uso del congiuntivo, non dovremo far altro che rispettare il normale ordine della frase affermativa:

> L’uso del congiuntivo in questa frase **è corretto**?

Qualora invece fosse la frase portata ad esempio il tema della nostra domanda, dovremo mettere «in questa frase» in un posizione di rilievo, dislocandola a sinistra, anzi, «anticipandola» o, viceversa, posticipandola:

> **In questa frase**, l’uso del congiuntivo è corretto?
>
> L’uso del congiuntivo è corretto, **in questa frase**?

Comment: Non dovresti dire "potremo" invece di "dovremo" nell'ultimo paragrafo? Mi sembra che quest'ultimo significato sarebbe espresso anche se "in questa frase" fosse nel mezzo della frase. Mettere qualcosa in posizione di rilievo è sempre facoltativo.

Answer (score 3):

Partirei citando il tuo passo sposandone la tesi

> Per le frasi interrogative senza interrogativi l'ordine di base delle parti della frase è uguale a quello delle frasi affermative; come per queste, esso varia a seconda del valore che si vuole attribuire ai singoli elementi. Normalmente si tende a mettere in fondo alla frase la parte su cui si concentra la domanda.

L'interrogativa diretta ha una precisa cadenza nell'intonazione della frase che la distingue da un periodo semplice. Il problema principale è che questa intonazione varia molto da regione a regione e non di rado capita che due italiani di regioni lontane parlandosi non si accorgano quando una frase è interrogativa poichè non è l'ordine delle parole a far scaturire l'effetto interrogativo ma l'intonazione.

Precisato questo è la stessa tonalità che porta ad evidenziare quale parte della frase sia l'oggetto principale della richiesta, non la collocazione all'interno della frase. L'intonazione può infatti portare a chiedere due cose diverse mantenendo l'esatto ordine di parole.

Ecco un esempio (nota che sono messe in maisucolo le parole da leggere accentuate con la pronuncia):

> L'uso del congiuntivo è corretto IN QUESTA FRASE?

. In questo caso si sta chiedendo se è questa la frase in cui il congiuntivo è corretto.

> L'uso del congiuntivo È CORRETTO in questa frase?

In questo caso si sta chiedendo se il congiuntivo è corretto in questo contesto.

Per lo scritto è buona idea rifarsi alle indicazioni dell'estratto già citato, mantendo vicino al punto interrogativo, ossia alla fine, il principale oggetto di richiesta. (es. l'ultima frase citata potrebbe diventare "L'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase è corretto?"

Answer (score 1):

Gli esempi riportati dal libro che usi come riferimento sono esemplificativi. I casi che riporti possono essere completati, per chiarire su quali aspetti si concentri la domanda, così:

> - È corretto l'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase?  (possibile completamento: Oppure va usato l'indicativo?)
>
> oppure
>
> - L'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase è corretto?  (possibile completamento: Oppure è assolutamente sbagliato?)

Un altro esempio tratto da [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5457/707):

> - È corretto dire "un terzo d'ora"?  (possibile completamento: Oppure si usa 20 minuti?)
>
> oppure
>
> - Dire "un terzo d'ora" è corretto?  (possibile completamento: Oppure non è mai utilizzato?)

Come inoltre detto nell'altra risposta, le inflessioni sono ugualmente utilizzate per dare enfasi all'aspetto che interessa nell'italiano orale. È nello scritto che l'enfasi va sottolineata utilizzando un ordine che rispetti le regole indicate nella grammatica.